# Incorrect answer - Simultaneous Differential Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

The questions states solve for y such that
$$y' = \begin{bmatrix}
    -4 & 2 & 1 \\
    1 & -3 & 1 \\
    3 & -3 & -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}y , y(0)= c = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\5\\3 \end{bmatrix}$$

The general solution is $y=ce^{At}$ where A is the above 3x3 matrix.
We find the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors:

$e_{-5} = \begin{bmatrix} -1\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$
$e_{-2} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

and the generalised eigenvector for -2

$e_{-2} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$

We then want to find c as a linear combination of our eigenvalues, and the result is:

$ c = 5 \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix} + 4\begin{bmatrix} -1\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$

Therefore soln = $ce^{At}$ = $e^{At} (5t \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix} + 4\begin{bmatrix} -1\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix})$

Adding a t above to the one vector because we have a generalised eigenvector.

And since $e^{At}v = e^{\lambda t}v$, we can write our solution as
$ y = 4e^{-5t}\begin{bmatrix} -1\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix} -e^{-2t}\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix} + 5te^{-2t}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$. However my solution solution is wrong. The correct one is

$ y = 4e^{-5t}\begin{bmatrix} -1\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix} + e^{-2t}\begin{bmatrix} 5\\5\\-1 \end{bmatrix} - te^{-2t}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$

I suspected that there may be multiple correct answers, however i'm not sure. What have i done wrong?

Comment: Yes the dimension of the kernal of (A+2I) is 1. Therefore i solved the kernal of (A+2I)^2 to get the generalised eigenvalue for -2 and got the result above.

Comment: Hence why my generalised eigenvector for -2 is then (0,0,1)?

Comment: I have done this havent i?